# Transfer to a separate js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a noob in javascript, I need to hide a piece of code that I use in html in a separate js file and use it in several pages of the site, how can I do this?

This is the code that protects mail from spambots:

```
<a href="mailto:testx@testsitex.com" onmouseover="this.href=this.href.replace(/x/g,'');">test@testsite.com</a>
```

How can I transfer this code `onmouseover="this.href=this.href.replace(/x/g,'');"` to a separate js file and then use it here?

Comment: Hide it from who exactly, and why? Putting it in a separate file won't hide it, if someone is determined to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a class to your email links

```
<a href="mailto:testx@testsitex.com" class="protected">test@testsite.com</a>
```

create a js file `mouseover.js` and add this code to it:

```
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{
      if(e.target.className === 'protected') e.target.href=e.target.href.replace(/x/g,'');
    });
```

and add this file to every page that contains email links (can be more)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mouseover.js"></script>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{
  if(e.target.className === 'protected') {
  e.target.href=e.target.href.replace(/x/g,'');
  console.log(e.target.href);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="mailto:testx1@testsitex.com" class="protected">test1@testsite.com</a>
<a href="mailto:testx2@testsitex.com" class="protected">test2@testsite.com</a>
<a href="mailto:testx3@testsitex.com" class="protected">test3@testsite.com</a>
<a href="mailto:testx4@testsitex.com" class="protected">test4@testsite.com</a>
<a href="mailto:testx5@testsitex.com" class="protected">test5@testsite.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example unicode and unescape function:

```
var hidden = unescape("\u0048\u0069\u0064\u0064\u0065\u006e \u006d\u0065\u0073\u0073\u0061\u0067\u0065\u0021");
```